# É possível iniciar o serverless-offline pelo JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

O plugin [serverless-offline](https://serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline/) é usado para iniciar uma aplicação baseada no framework [Serverless](https://serverless.com/). Para iniciar, é usado o comando `serverless offline [options]` ou `sls offline [options]`

É possível iniciar o mesmo através do JavaScript? Algo como:

```
const slsOffline = require('serverless-offline');

slsOffline.start(options)
    .then(() => {/* ... */});
```

Motivo: testar o código. Na documentação é sugerido testar diretamente os handlers, porém isso pode deixar passar erros no `serverless.yml`, como escrever o nome da rota, parâmetro ou método incorretamente, ou até esquecer de criar a rota depois de criar o handler

Tentei executar o comando que inicia a aplicação e que roda os testes juntos:

```
npm run start && npm run test
```

Porém, como o `start` se mantém executando até que seja interrompido e a aplicação pare, os testes nunca são executados ou são executados depois da aplicação ter parado. Executar os scripts em terminais diferentes é complicado para automatizar os processos de desenvolvimento e deploy, como usar o Bitbucket Pipeline para executar o build, test e deploy

Comment: Está em inglês mas acredito que esse site possa ajudar https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/serverless-nodejs-starter.html

Comment: Talvez isto te ajude: https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline#usage-with-invoke

Answer (score -3):

O caminho mais fácil para você, é fazer testes unitários para que você não precise inicar a sua aplicação inteira para poder fazer os seus testes não-unitários.

Mas se você ainda deseja fazer isso, você deve procurar como executar comandos de linha de comando via javaScript. [Esse link pode ser útil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10187277/10008842).